# Android remove onInterceptTouchEvent when tapping

Tags: android, android-listview, touch, android-gesture

Hello right now I'm developing a custom view where there'll be 2 listview that the header can be stacked each other like this picture :

[image]

```
               ||
               ||
               \/
```

[image]

I already succeed to create this view, by overriding overscrolled and intercept all touch and playing with the margin of the header contents. but the problem now is because I intercept all touch now I can't tap the content of the listview, I know the flow of the touch is from ACTION_DOWN -> ACTION_MOVE -> ACTION_UP, and then when I dispatch the event to the child the tap is working but the scroll isn't working at all.

So for now the flow for my view is like this onInterceptTouchEvent -> onTouch -> gestureListener (or with overscroll)

this is some part of my code

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}

@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        topListViewHeight = lvFirstListView.getTotalHeight() - rlFirstHeader.getHeight();
        if(isBottomScrollable) {
            listGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            lvSecondListView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        } else {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Is there anybody here have an idea about this? Any suggestion is very appreciated and if you need more question about this question please ask me.
Thanks before

Comment: try what happens when you don't `return true;` everywhere because that means you have handled that event and nothing else should get it. See http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

Comment: @zapl Yes, I guess that's one of the cause, right now I'm reading the scrollview source code and will try to implement the concept from the scrollview to differentiate tap and drag, thanks for the advice though